# Keep layout the same when adding a tab [SOLUTION BELOW CODE]

Tags: c#

I am quite new at C# so I need everything as simple as possible, I have coded a web browser with tabs, when I click add tab however it only Opens a webrowser in the new tab on google.co.uk but what I need is the new tab to have an adressbar and a navigate button for me to be able to navigate to another URL in the new tab. Basically what I want to get is an add tab button that adds a tab with a totally seperate Web Browser and a seperate adressbar and a seperate Navigate button. Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tb = new TabPage("Tab");
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        wb.Navigate("www.google.co.uk");
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tb);
        tb.Controls.Add(wb);
        tabControl1.SelectTab(tb);
    }

    private void closeAltF4ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void addTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tb = new TabPage("Tab");
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        wb.Navigate("www.google.co.uk");
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tb);
        tb.Controls.Add(wb);
        tabControl1.SelectTab(tb);
        tb.Controls.Add(new TextBox());


    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void removeTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
    }

}
```

}

SOLUTION:

I got it to work with the Usercontrol, I designed a Usercontrol form and then added it into the tabs using this code:

```
TabPage tb = new TabPage("Tab");
        MenuStrip ms = new MenuStrip();
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tb);
        tb.Controls.Add(ms);
        tb.Controls.Add(new UserControl1()); 
        tabControl1.SelectTab(tb);
```

Comment: `private void closeAltF4ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { this.Close(); }` - are you using this to close the form or the application?  If the latter, I would suggest that you use `Application.Exit()`.

Comment: You might want to make a usercontrol and add it to the tabpage. That way when you click add populate the tab with the usercontrol and go from there.

Comment: Brian to answer ur question Im using it to exit the Form, and timmy what do you mean by usercontrol im not familiar with that. thanks

Comment: I am not sure what it is that you are asking. You say "I need ..." some things that you already have... and "I want ..." some other stuff that you have not written any code for. As timmy said, create a usercontrol and add that to your tab page.

Comment: Is there a tutorial online that shows me how to create a usercontrol? because I have no Idea how

Comment: Ah that was simple Ive figured out how to make a Usercontrol and now I just need to learn how to use it, will try thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user control is the best way to keep the same layout. You can think of it like a panel. It can keep your controls grouped and maintain the same look. Add your website GUI to the panel then add the panel control to the TabControl.

Something like

```
 TabPage tb = new TabPage("Tab");
    MenuStrip ms = new MenuStrip();
    ms.Items.Add("Add");
    ms.items[0].Click += new EventHandler(AddMenu_Click);
    tb.Controls.Add(ms);
    tb.Controls.Add(new UserControl(tabControl1)); //If you need to update tab text
      tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tb);
```

This would create a menu strip on each tabpage and then your user control or "panel" would fill in the rest.

Comment: Thanks timmy ill make sure to check that out as soon as I finish my UserControl